Dual boot problem
I have been using both Windows 10 and Ubuntu on my laptop. A Windows update was installed and following this update the boot loader did not give the option to select which system to boot from. I can access Ubuntu via the UEFI but need to repair the bootloader.How do I do this?

In UEFI settings, you can set Ubuntu to be the default boot option.

Windows may turn fast startup back on. Or other Windows settings  in addition to making itself default boot after update (grub may do this on major update, also).
